PiHole Webpage working but not DNS service
Pi Hole is running as a Docker, on my Synology NAS.
In my Network everything works fine and I can access the webpage/control panel over the IP 192.168.2.25 and Ads are successfully blocked.
In my router I opened the Ports 80 and 53, to the device with the IP 192.168.2.25.
I can access the control panel just fine from outside the network using my public ipv4 address.
But adding this address to the DNS settings of my devices results in pages not loading because a connection is not possible.
Thanks for your help in advance.

DNS uses UDP, so perhaps your router is not letting this traffic through. Regardless this is not a programming question. This is possibly a support question for your router manufacturer.
